# how to know if a point is inside the playable area on isometric maps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d tiled maps, i need to know if a touch is done inside the isometric map. Isometric maps have a diamond shape.

When i set a new position i would use a min,max but as it is in diamond shape... can not be sure is inside the map..

This would be the validator if the space was a square, but as this is diamond it won't work.

```
-(CGPoint)validateInsideMap:(CGPoint)position{
    int x,y;
    x = MAX(_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width , position.x);
    x = MIN(0, x);
    y = MAX(_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height , position.y);
    y = MIN(0, y);
    return ccp(x, y);
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: I ran into this before. Check the cocos2d tilemap code, it should really not crash on access out of bounds but return a nil tile. The fix there is easy compared to testing it yourself. The method in question was something about tile coord conversion.

Comment: yes normally it crashes cause there no exists that tmx position... but i would like to return the closest tile... i was thinking about converting the touch position into tile coordinates, but as it would be out of the map it will crash... before i can compare if the tile coordinate is inside of the map... :/

Comment: guess that the only solution is to invalidate actions if touched outside :/ thank you

Comment: i got it solved, i just validate that the tile returned were inside the map bounds, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pixels was a little complicated to calculate if the touch was inside the map, so i just needed to convert the position in pixels to the tile system, then just validate that tile was inside the map bounds, else return the closest one.

Thats made with this algorithm:

```
 -(CGPoint) tilePosFromLocation:(CGPoint)location{
    float mapHeight = _tileMap.mapSize.height;
    float tileWidth = _tileMap.tileSize.width;
    float tileHeight = _tileMap.tileSize.height;

    CGPoint tilePosDiv = CGPointMake(location.x/tileWidth, location.y/tileHeight);
    float invereseTileY = mapHeight - tilePosDiv.y;


    float posX = (int)(invereseTileY + tilePosDiv.x - (_tileMap.mapSize.width*0.5));
    float posY = (int)(invereseTileY - tilePosDiv.x + (_tileMap.mapSize.width*0.5));

    posX=MAX(0, posX);
    posX=MIN(_tileMap.mapSize.width - 1, posX);
    posY=MAX(0, posY);
    posY=MIN(_tileMap.mapSize.height - 1, posY);

    return CGPointMake(posX, posY);
}
```

This way there always be a tile inside the bounds of the map retourned, so no problem if the touch was outside